# DataGridView need guidance with that

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Thank you for your time in advance, I need some help, I want to create a DataGridView in Windows form, and in this grid I want to enter data and when I hit enter it should **save** that data to database and create another line, I tried to find a good tutorial on it but didn’t succeeded. if there is any good example please let me know
And please I do NOT need the grid with save update etc buttons, It should save data upon hit enter and cursor moves to the next line of the grid
If there is any tutorial or example please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply catch the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key in the `DataGridView.KeyDown` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        yourSaveRoutine();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you've a tutorial on this or a complete example as I've no idea related to winforms Thanks

Comment: To __hook up__ the code you doubleclick on the `KeyDown` event in the DGV's property&actions- tab (the one with the flash). This creates the event stub and there you add the little snippet I posted. - If you are asking how to __save__ the content of a DGV, that would be a different question. I assume you have code for that in the Button you spoke of.

Comment: I don't want to use any sort of button, the data is entered in the grid columns and when pressed enter key that is saved to db, I've done other stuff like save data in in to grid on button click but not when there is just grid

Comment: for example please see this  screen short
http://prntscr.com/4snm9u

Comment: Sure. All you need to do it to add a method for saving the data. It will get called when `Enter` is pressed. To find out how to write such a routine, Google for _c# datagridview save data_ and you'll get many hits. You may want to add _databound_ to the search words __if__ that is the case.